# How to extract a substring

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I'm making a simple HTML form for the user data submit.
I can also intercept user errors (I can receive different strings depending on the type of error) .

I don't know the Javascript syntax for Regular Expression, 
but I would like to know how to make a string match with another string.

For example:
this is the console:

```
Error: Invalid phone number format.
at Request.extractError (vendor.bundle.js:14836)
at Request.callListeners (vendor.bundle.js:17756)
at Request.emit (vendor.bundle.js:17728)
at Request.emit (vendor.bundle.js:16385)
```

I would like to create a switch case that can capture the various errors through substrings, like this:

```
 switch(err) {
   case "Invalid phone number format"
   console.log("Error phone");
   break;
```

I don't know how to extract the substring "Invalid phone number format" from the much longer string that I showed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
let string = 'here is a long error string that contains substring error phone';
let re = /error phone|error string|foo/g;

string.match(re);
```